# Node client-sessions not deleting on closing browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, session

I'm using [mozilla/node-client-sessions](https://github.com/mozilla/node-client-sessions) to manage the user log-in. I have set 'ephemeral : true', however the cookie doesn't get deleted on closing the browser. Any Suggestions?

Thanks already for the help!

```
app.use(sessions({
  cookieName : 'userLoggedIn',
  secret : 'asfdgijhascbjaksgdoausdasnmldaspdoxja',
  duration : 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
  activeDuration : 60 * 60 * 1000,
  cookie:{
    httpOnly : true, //cookie only accessable to http requests, not javascript
    ephemeral : true  //deletes cookie on closing browser
  }
}));
```